# Enter only digits in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dom-events

I was using this function to enter only digits in to textbox and it worked.

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

but customer asked me to restrict `-` sign so user should not enter - sign. So I modified the code to this:

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode == 45)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

and now it not works, it allows letters too, why?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/oo4s9j1p/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `||` in the group:

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  var bool = (charCode > 31) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 || String.fromCharCode(charCode) == "-");

  return !bool;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `||` instead of `&&` in your test.
On my `azerty` keyboard, the `-` sign charcode is `54`, not `45`.

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 || charCode == 45) )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvhw70h6/)

**Edit**

Looks like your charCode [is correct](http://www.ascii-code.com/). The `54` value comes from my `azerty` keyboard.
Nevertheless, you should use `||` instead of `&&` in your check.

Comment: on my win machine `45` is the `-`?

Comment: I'm using an `azerty` keyboard maybe this is linked and my fiddle works with it. The point is : use `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: @cl3m yes you are correct for the condition and if the case is crossbrowser then i guess `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) == "-"` match would be better choice.